# How is answering a question possible after even question closed?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, questions, answers

I just saw a bizarre situation on Stackoverflow. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007836/i-cant-find-an-another-way-to-do-it-right) question was closed at `14:36:35` but [Habib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961113/habib) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19007876/447156) at `14:36:39`

How is this possible? Closing a question take a few seconds?

Comment: I was about to post the same question :) . I guess it has to do something with the real time updates, which I am not getting due to some reason.